# Insert Additional HTML every time row value changes

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I would like to print out "multiple tables" from one SQL query. The logic being that each time a row is printed with a **new value** that differs from the value of the previous row, to create a new table in HTML.

Maybe something like this

```
This stuff is Assigned to JOE
-----------------------------------
Assigned to |Column1   |Column2  
-----------------------------------
Joe         |1         |A
Joe         |2         |B
Joe         |3         |C


This stuff is Assigned to Adam
-----------------------------------
Assigned to |Column1   |Column2  
-----------------------------------
Adam        |1         |A
Adam        |2         |B


This stuff is Assigned to Patrick
-----------------------------------
Assigned to |Column1   |Column2  
-----------------------------------
Patrick     |1         |A
Patrick     |2         |B
Patrick     |3         |C
```

I did a test run of my code, a basic PHP If-Statement that tried to detect if the Variable from the previous row had not changed. And if it did, then insert some code.

```
$tsql = "
SELECT 
    id
    AssignedTo
    Column1
    Column2
FROM somewhere
ORDER BY AssignedTo ASC";  

/* Execute the query. */  
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql);  

/* I will set this variable to whatever for now */ 
$AssignedTo = '';

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC))  
{       

If ($AssignedTo != $row[1])
    {
    $AssignedTo = $row[1];
    echo "<h1>This is assigned to ".$AssignedTo."</h1>";
    echo "<table><tr>headings</tr>";
    }

echo "<tr>bla bla</tr>";

}
```

But the result turned out something like this:

```
This stuff is Assigned to JOE
--------------------------------
This stuff is Assigned to Adam
--------------------------------
This stuff is Assigned to Patrick
--------------------------------
//Rest of the Rows down here after
```

I don't understand why my "This stuff is assigned to" looped above all of the rest of the table rows, even though the **if-statement** was inside **while**.

Thanks

Comment: There is no `</table>` before you start a new one. In your if see if `$AssignedTo` is not blank and if it is not blank add a `</table>` before starting the next one.

Comment: Good idea! Will add that in. Still does not solve the fact that the actual rows are after all of these "assigned to" people loop through.

Comment: Closing the table should fix it. When you stack up a bunch of tables without closing them where rows end up is quite unpredictable :)

Comment: Let me try it out, I never thought of this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never closed your table(s) once you have started them.

```
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC))
{

If ($AssignedTo != $row[1])
    {
    if ($AssignedTo != '') {
        echo '</table>';
    }
    $AssignedTo = $row[1];
    echo "<h1>This is assigned to ".$AssignedTo."</h1>";
    echo "<table><tr>headings</tr>";
    }

echo "<tr>bla bla</tr>";

}
```